# Independent multi-monitor dock configuration

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-dock

I have GNOME version 42.5 and multi-monitor setup. Is it possible to have an independent  configurations for a dock for each monitor. For example to have a dock on left on the left monitor and on right on the right monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Dash to Panel extension and it does pretty much everything I need. Except that favorite icons are presented in one column if you place the panel on the side - left or right, even if there is enough space. It would be nice to arrange the icons in several rows, saving more space.